# Подойдут ли пакеты debian для ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, debian, apt-get, dpkg, deb

Устанавливаю на ПК с ОС Debian пакет с зависимостями через apt-get, затем я достаю все deb-пакеты из /var/cache/apt/archives и с помощью флэшки перенесу на другой ПК на ОС Ubuntu, выполню `dpkg -i *.deb` , я хочу знать подойдут ли эти пакеты от Debian к Ubuntu? Все вышеописанное нужно для установки пакета с зависимостями на ПК без интернета.

Comment: «подойти»-то подойдут, даже будут благополучно распакованы в ф.с., только вот конфликты и неудовлетворённые зависимости практически гарантированы. что с высокой вероятностью приведёт к (частичной) неработоспособности программ, входящих в эти пакеты. // надо совершенно по иному действовать, если вы хотите получить «гарантированный успех».

Comment: @alexanderbarakin в директорию /var/cache/apt/archives скачиваются и пакеты, и зависимости. Скачиваю на "чистую ОС", то есть будет много зависимостей, я думаю зависимости должны быть удовлетворены после установки на ПК без интернета. Спасибо за ответ, на мой главный вопрос Вы дали ответ.

Comment: зависимости будут совершенно разные — там же совершенно разные пакетные базы. я бы не рекомендовал ваш подход — с моей точки зрения, вероятность получить «всё работающее» — ничтожна, а вероятность привести в неработоспособное состояние всю систему — далека от нуля.

Comment: @Даниил, кто мешает качать с зеркал бубна? Почему зеркала дебиана? Кто мешает качнуть с зеркал CentOS, OpenSuse и пройтись прогой `alien`?

Comment: @donRumata как все это сделать? Какие именно зеркала?

Comment: Попробуй копнуть в сторону `apt-mirror`, `debmirror`, `debpartial-mirror`.

Comment: @donRumata а что если добавить репозитории ubuntu на мой debian, ничего не устанавливая скачать deb пакеты для ubuntu? Можно ли так поступить?

Comment: Какой тебе софт нужен в репах дебиана которого нет в убунте и ppa?

Comment: @donRumata Мне нужен GIMP со всеми зависимостями для LUbuntu. На ПК с LUbuntu нет интернета, но есть дома ПК с интернетом на Debian. Я думаю пакеты Ubuntu должны подойти к Ubuntu(ведь у LUbuntu есть доступ к репозиториям Ubuntu по умолчанию), но как мне все это скачать находясь на Debian?

Comment: Я бы решил эту проблему поднятием безгуёвой виртуалки с убунтой (метров 128 оперативы под это дело - за глаза) и ковырял бы по ссх те пакеты которые я написал раньше. Более красивый способ не знаю.

Comment: @donRumata ну а сработает ли спомоб с добавлением репозиториев?

Comment: Ну тогда у тебя будут браться во внимание пакеты из ВСЕХ реп. Наверное должен проканать вариант с заменой реп, обновлением индексов, выкачиванием нужных пакетов, возвращением адресов реп обратно и снова обновлением индексов. Но это, имхо, ещё больший костыль, чем виртуалка.

Comment: @donRumata а что если я добавлю репозиторий, выполню apt-get update, затем скачаю deb без установки, а потом вернусь на свои репозитории и снова apt-get update?

Comment: Ну примерно это я и написал выше.