# Есть ли какие-то ключи для команды apt-get для загрузки пакета и всех зависимостей в какуе-то папку, даже если пакет установлен

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apt-get

Например GIMP.

```
apt-get --какиетоКлючи gimp /папка/для/зависимостейИПакета/
```

P.S. Мне нужно достать все зависимости, а затем установить через dpkg на другой ПК с Ubuntu без интернета.

Comment: зачем вам это нужно?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman что бы достать все зависимости, а за тем установить через dpkg на другой ПК с ubuntu без интернета.

Comment: добавьте эту информацию в вопрос и исправьте заголовок

Comment: Чё-то такое уже было. И я даже чё-то отвечал. А `aptoncd` не прокатит?

Comment: @donRumata, https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/649904/178576

Comment: Вот тут куча самых разных вариантов: https://askubuntu.com/q/974

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, да, оно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

если в данный момент обе системы находятся в **абсолютно синхронном состоянии** (с точки зрения установленных пакетов — и названий, и **версий**), и это **всего лишь разовая акция**, то подойдёт опция `-d` (`--download-only`):

```
$ sudo apt-get -d install имя-пакета
```

конечно, не забудьте перед выполнением этой команды обновить список пакетов:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
```

скачиваться файлы с пакетами будут, как и обычно, в каталог `/var/cache/apt/archives/`.

после переноса их на второй компьютер установите их командой:

```
$ sudo dpkg -i /путь/к/каталогу/с/пакетами/*.deb
```

---

если системы **не находятся в синхронном состоянии**, с большой долей вероятности эта команда завершится ошибкой — не хватит каких-нибудь зависимостей. их придётся скачать (на первом компьютере) командой

```
$ apt-get download имя-недостающего-пакета
```

(файл будет сохранён в текущий каталог), перенести на второй компьютер (в тот же самый каталог) и повторить последнюю команду `dpkg -i ...` (в зависимости от степени «рассинхронизации» пакетной базы подобное перетаскивание может потребоваться проделать несколько раз подряд, скачивая и добавляя всё новые пакеты).

---

если это **не разовая акция**, то и на первом компьютере эти пакеты следует **тоже** установить — именно для поддержания упомянутого синхронного состояния между двумя системами. т.е., никаких там опций `-d`, простая установка:

```
$ sudo apt-get install имя-пакета
```

повторюсь: скачиваться файлы с пакетами будут, как и обычно, в каталог `/var/cache/apt/archives/`. копируйте их на вторую машину и устанавливайте, как и написано выше, командой `dpkg -i ...`.

---

кстати, **если системы рассинхронизированы** и требуемый пакет уже установлен на первом компьютере, то ни с опцией `-d`, ни без неё скачивания не будет производиться.

один из возможных вариантов выхода:

1. сделайте на втором компьютере файл `/etc/apt/sources.list` и содержимое каталога `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` абсолютно такими же, как и на первом компьютере.
2. на первом компьютере обновите списки пакетов:

   ```
   $ sudo apt-get update
   ```

   и перенесите эти списки (хранящиеся в каталоге `/var/lib/apt/lists`) на второй компьютер.
3. на втором компьютере выполните:

   ```
   $ apt-get -s install имя-пакета
   ```

   ничего устанавливаться (благодаря опции `-s`/`--simulate`) не будет, но вы получите список пакетов, которые необходимо скачать, сразу ниже строки

   ```
   The following NEW packages will be installed:
   ```
4. скопируйте этот список, и на первой машине скачайте их в текущий каталог:

   ```
   $ apt-get download список необходимых пакетов ...
   ```
5. перенеся эти файлы на второй компьютер, установите их, как и написано выше, командой `dpkg -i ...`

Comment: Как-нибудь можно этот процесс автоматизировать? Скажем, на втором компьютере получить список недостающих пакетов, скачать их на первом и скопировать на второй. Хотелось бы уместиться в не более чем пару команд и обойтись без изменения конфигурации первого компьютера. Это возможно?

Comment: Возможно, лучшим вариантом было бы получить список уже установленных пакетов на втором компьютере и скачать с первого компьютера желаемый пакет вместе с недостающими зависимостями (и обновлениями). А это как можно организовать?

Comment: @mymedia, вот десять лет назад я описал [процесс полной синхронизации](https://unixforum.org/index.php?showtopic=36952&view=findpost&p=368731). как-то криво открывается ссылка. мой пост можно опознать по аватарке.

Comment: @mymedia: если по локальной сети можно достучаться, то можно `apt-cacher-ng` поставить [или  `squid-deb-proxy`](https://askubuntu.com/q/3503/3712)

Answer (score 1):

Возможный вариант действий заключается во *временном* копировании списка установленных пакетов и их версий с компьютера без интернета (обозначим его буквой А) на тот, что с интернетом (обозначим буквой Б), скачивании на Б недостающих пакетов и обновлений (по желанию) и копировании их на А.

1. Очистите на Б кэш пакетов — `sudo apt clean`.
2. Возьмите с А системный файл `/var/lib/dpkg/status` и скопируйте его на Б, предварительно сделав копию.
3. Также поступите с `/etc/apt/sources.list`, `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/*`, `/etc/apt/preferences` и `/etc/apt/preferences.d/*`.
4. Скачайте желаемый пакет — `sudo apt install -d пакет`.
5. Скопируйте файлы `/var/cache/apt/archives/*.deb` с Б на А.
6. Установите их все на А — `sudo dpkg -i *.deb`.
7. Верните Б в прежнее состояние.

Изложенный способ не без недостатков. Например, нужно на Б иметь административный доступ, что не всегда возможно. Более того, существует риск поломки системы на Б, скажем, если во время этих манипуляций запустится автообновление.

Впрочем, есть способ обойти эти недостатки и автоматизировать процесс с помощью программы [apt-offline](https://apt-offline.alioth.debian.org/) из одноимённого пакета. Весь процесс будет выглядеть примерно следующим образом.

```
sudo apt-offline set packages.sig --install-packages gimp  # на компьютере А
apt-offline get packages.sig  # на Б, предварительно скопировав туда файл .sig
sudo apt-offline install /tmp/apt-offline-downloads-1180  # эту папку следует
                 # скопировать на компьютер А, цифры на конце могут отличаться
sudo apt-get install gimp  # потом устанавливаем GIMP на А привычной командой
```

Файл `packages.sig` имеет простой текстовый формат, в котором будут перечислены URL пакетов для загрузки. По идее, их можно скачать из любой ОС и сложить в папку, которая затем окажется на компьютере А.